# Is there a way to get VS 2013's SQL Server Object Explorer to script defaults?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

We ran into an issue today where bugs were popping up on a remote site, and traced it back to a developer using the SQL Server Object Explorer to drill into a DB and script out a table with Script As > Create To > New Query Window, and then passing the create script on to the deployment scripts.

However, unlike SSMS this does not script out table defaults by.. erm.. default, and we haven't been able to find a way to make it do this. If you open the "Designer" in VS you see the defaults on the columns, but they are never scripted out.

Has anyone seen else seen this? Any tips on how to prevent this (pretty easy to miss) condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed Visual Studio Premium or Visual Studio Ultimate, you have access to all the database features. If you do not have Visual Studio Premium or Visual Studio Ultimate, but instead have Visual Studio Professional, only a subset of the features are available.

For a list of the database features that are supported by [Data-tier Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362013(VS.100).aspx), see Features Supported in Data-tier Applications on the Microsoft Web site. If you use features in your database that are not supported by Data-tier Applications, you should instead use a database project to manage changes to your database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd193245(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. This seems like a trivial thing to exclude from the Pro edition. It's definitely not a driver to upgrade editions, just an annoyance. We are going to go berate and ridicule them on Microsoft Connect until they fix it.